# How to joining 2 variables in other variable

Tags: c++

See the example to understand

```
int rnd = rand() %10;
string Folder = "c://foldername";
string final_name = Folder + rnd; // here the target

/* I want the result like that (random folder name)
foldername5
foldername10
foldername3
foldername20
foldername17
*/
```

Comment: pet peeve: `rand() / (RAND_MAX / 10 + 1)` see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ you use stringstream to convert integers to strings.

```
int rnd = rand() %10;
string Folder = "c://foldername";
stringstream ss;
ss << Folder << rnd;
string final_name = ss.str(); // here the target
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::stringstream` as:

```
#include <sstream> //include this

std::stringstream ss;
ss << Folder  << rnd;
string final_name = ss.str();
```

Or you can write this just in one line:

```
string final_name = stringbuilder() << Folder  << rnd;
```

All that it needs a small utility class:

```
struct stringbuilder
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   template<typename T>
   stringbuilder & operator << (const T &data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   operator std::string() { return ss.str(); }
};
```

Using this class, you can create `std::string` on the fly as:

```
void f(const std::string & file ) {}

f(stringbuilder() << Folder  << rnd);

std::string s = stringbuilder() << 25  << " is greater than " << 5 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the best way to do this is to use a `stringstream`:

```
#include<sstream>

...

std::stringstream stream;
stream << "c://foldername" << rand() %10;
stream.str(); // now contains both path and number
```

Answer (score 2):

Say this:

```
std::string final_name = Folder + std::to_string(rnd);
```

If you have an old compiler that doesn't support C++11, you can use `boost::lexical_cast`, or `std::snprintf`, or string streams.

Comment: to_string function work with data type (long long, long double) but not work with (int, float)

Comment: @LionKing: I doubt that, as the `int` overload is explicitly required by the standard (21.5.7)... perhaps you have a broken compiler? You could convert the value to `long int` or `long long int` if that helps, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Convert `rnd` (it is in integer type) to `string` type then do the same

```
string final_name = Folder + rnd;
```